# Why do I get "'str' object has no attribute 'read'" when trying to use `json.load` on a string?

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2, attributeerror

In Python I'm getting an error:

```
Exception:  (<type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>,
AttributeError("'str' object has no attribute 'read'",), <traceback object at 0x1543ab8>)
```

Given python code:

```
def getEntries (self, sub):
    url = 'http://www.reddit.com/'
    if (sub != ''):
        url += 'r/' + sub
    
    request = urllib2.Request (url + 
        '.json', None, {'User-Agent' : 'Reddit desktop client by /user/RobinJ1995/'})
    response = urllib2.urlopen (request)
    jsonStr = response.read()
    
    return json.load(jsonStr)['data']['children']
```

What does this error mean and what did I do to cause it?

Answer (score 281, accepted):

The problem is that for `json.load` you should pass a file like object with a `read` function defined. So either you use [`json.load(response)`](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html#json.load) or [`json.loads(response.read())`](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html#json.loads).

Comment: I don't understand this...how does doing read() solve the problem? The response still doesn't have a read function. Are we supposed to put the string in some object with a read function?

Comment: @yourfriendzak read closely, it is two different functions with very similar names. `json.load()` takes a file like object with a `read()` method, `json.loads()` takes a string. It's easy to miss the "s" at the end and think they are the same method.

Comment: Thanks to Joshmaker's comment, json.loads() can parse string for JSON data!

Comment: @yourfriendzak This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835559/parsing-values-from-a-json-file-in-python) would point you that with `open` you can achieve that.

Comment: Thanks Joshmaker. Your andwe is useful to me. load, loads ....How un-intuitive names given by originators of library. Really illogical

Comment: @MANISHZOPE the `s` stands for "string". I agree that the standard library has some serious issues overall with how things are named, and this is a good example of how it gets messed up.

Comment: @kosii I request you to what @Joshmaker said in your answer. It would be more helpful to users who just tent to overlook that tiny `s`

Comment: I hope the person who thought `json.loads` was more self-explanatory than `json.load_string` has been fired right after the release.

Answer (score 65):

Ok, this is an old thread but. 
I had a same issue, my problem was I used `json.load` instead of `json.loads`

This way, json has no problem with loading any kind of dictionary.

[Official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)

> json.load - Deserialize fp (a .read()-supporting text file or binary file containing a JSON document) to a Python object using this conversion table.
>
> json.loads - Deserialize s (a str, bytes or bytearray instance containing a JSON document) to a Python object using this conversion table.

Answer (score 41):

You need to open the file first. This doesn't work:

```py
json_file = json.load('test.json')
```

But this works:

```py
f = open('test.json')
json_file = json.load(f)
```

Comment: I found the error in the question when trying to open a file instead of a request response in the question. Clearly, at the backend, json is treating both similarly, and so this answer helped me. Clearly worth an upvote.

Comment: This answer is so straightforward. Thank you!

Answer (score 19):

**If you get a python error like this:**

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'some_method'
```

You probably poisoned your object accidentally by overwriting your object with a string.

**How to reproduce this error in python with a few lines of code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import json
def foobar(json):
    msg = json.loads(json)

foobar('{"batman": "yes"}')
```

**Run it, which prints:**

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'loads'
```

**But change the name of the variablename, and it works fine:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import json
def foobar(jsonstring):
    msg = json.loads(jsonstring)

foobar('{"batman": "yes"}')
```

This error is caused when you tried to run a method within a string.  String has a few methods, but not the one you are invoking.  So stop trying to invoke a method which String does not define and start looking for where you poisoned your object.

Comment: "loads" worked for me. Thank you for your solution

Answer (score 18):

```
AttributeError("'str' object has no attribute 'read'",)
```

This means exactly what it says: something tried to find a `.read` attribute on the object that you gave it, and you gave it an object of type `str` (i.e., you gave it a string).

The error occurred here:

```
json.load(jsonStr)['data']['children']
```

Well, you aren't looking for `read` anywhere, so it must happen in the `json.load` function that you called (as indicated by the full traceback). That is because `json.load` is trying to `.read` the thing that you gave it, but you gave it `jsonStr`, which currently names a string (which you created by calling `.read` on the `response`).

Solution: don't call `.read` yourself; the function will do this, and is expecting you to give it the `response` directly so that it can do so.

You could also have figured this out by reading the built-in Python documentation for the function (try `help(json.load)`, or for the entire module (try `help(json)`), or by checking the documentation for those functions on http://docs.python.org .

Answer (score 6):

Instead of json.load() use json.loads() and it would work:
ex:

```
import json
from json import dumps

strinjJson = '{"event_type": "affected_element_added"}'
data = json.loads(strinjJson)
print(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Open the file as a text file first

```
json_data = open("data.json", "r")
```

Now load it to dict

```
dict_data = json.load(json_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

So, don't use `json.load(data.read())` use `json.loads(data.read())`:

```
def findMailOfDev(fileName):
    file=open(fileName,'r')
    data=file.read();
    data=json.loads(data)
    return data['mail']
```

Answer (score 0):

use json.loads() function , put the s after that ... just a mistake btw i just realized after i searched error

```
def getEntries (self, sub):
url = 'http://www.reddit.com/'
if (sub != ''):
    url += 'r/' + sub

request = urllib2.Request (url + 
    '.json', None, {'User-Agent' : 'Reddit desktop client by /user/RobinJ1995/'})
response = urllib2.urlopen (request)
jsonStr = response.read()

return json.loads(jsonStr)['data']['children']
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

If you need to convert string to json. Then use loads() method instead of load(). load() function uses to load data from a file so used loads() to convert string to json object.

```
j_obj = json.loads('["label" : "data"]')
```